# How to extract C-shape(or other complex hollow shapes) from a image using openCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I have fount the following methods, but none of them seems to be working in this case, there the shape itself is hollow and the shape could rotate.

1. Finding contours and counting number of edges. Apparently, there is curve in the pattern, so edges is hard to be counted.
2. Hough Circle Transform. Only applicable to circles.

A example would be like:[image]

Comment: Did you try the Hough transform for circles? I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Quite true about @CrisLuengo’s comment: Hough transform world on partial circles. You may simply need to tweak some parameters, but even writing your own custom Hough transform from scratch to solve this one problem would be worth trying.